# Change any listening binding port to another

Tags: linux, networking

Let's say I have an application which always binds to the same address and port (e.g. tcp 0.0.0.0:8080)

If I run the same application again in another instance, it tries to bind to the same address and port, which are currently in use from the first execution of the application.

Is there a system wide way in Linux to change this (beforehand), using "fake/virtual" port mapping or some sort to have control over this?
(like a global port mapping table?)

It would also help to just change/override any listening port to another.

I am an administrator of my own machine and there is no way to change the binding/port from the application.

Comment: What is the application that can't told to listen on another port?

Comment: @Kusalananda The application is just an example for this question. It could be any application. I am just looking for an administrative way to "move/override/map" listening ports to another binding setting.

Comment: @Ben If an application is designed to be run multiple times on the same system it should have a way to solve the conflict, e.g. by providing a command line argument or configuration value for the port number. As a workaround you could run the application instances in VMs or containers and configure the port forwarding from different host ports to the same port in different guests/containers.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to change port from outside the application. It (application) must have some configuration ability to reassign the port it would listen.

Said that - you can go by proxi way. Each instance of the application should start on a different machine with different IP address. That can be a different physical box, or virtual machine, or virtual network interface (if the application allows to choose its IP on a machine with several IPs).

Once you have multiple instances of the app listening on 192.168.10.1:8080, 192.168.10.2:8080, 192.168.10.3:8080, etc - you can set up a proxi on the "main" IP and do a mapping like 192.168.1.1:8081->192.168.10.1:8080, 192.168.1.1:8082->192.168.10.2:8080, 192.168.1.1:8083->192.168.10.3:8080 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing, but [`redir`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/redir) can be perhaps useful to you.  It redirects incoming TCP connections to a specific port, to another specified IP address and port.